# Is it still possible to get a SIM card in China as a foreigner?

Tags: china, cellphones

According to the [prepaid SIM card wiki](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/China), it is possible to get a SIM card as a foreigner in certain "flagship" stores:

> The problem is recently, that most shops - even the small newsstands - only accept the machine-readable Chinese ID card. Foreign passports seem to be accepted only by the flagship stores of the providers (or at airports)

However, when I tried to buy a SIM card with data plan, they told me that they needed a Chinese ID Card (身份证), and it was not possible to register with a foreign passport. I tried 10-15 different phone stores in several major cities and they all refused.

Has anyone successfully registered a SIM card with a foreign passport recently, or is the wiki page out of date? If this is still possible, what are the "flagship" stores that do this?

Comment: At least in Russia you can often buy sim-cards from unofficial sellers without showing any ID. Perhaps that's the case in China too?

Comment: @JonathanReez, why would that be a case in china too?

Comment: in Hong Kong you can buy a sim-card without your  passport

Comment: Well, I got a SIM card from main store from China Unicom. I was working in Shanghai. I dont remember anything about deposit. But every month I would pay 80~150 RMB bill with 4G internet included. And note, before leaving China make sure, you cancel your number. other wise, It will bill you.

Comment: @アレックス because it's a developing country where the rules can often be bent going through unofficial channels. This is a commonality with just about every developing country in Asia, at least in my experience. There are a lot of rules in China, you do not have to in practice actually follow. It may be the case in China for this, it may not, really depends. I was able to buy a China Mobile SIM but that was years ago and I know they change the rules and enforcement thereof all the time.

Comment: @IvanMcA, I think that you're talking gibberish - developing country, rules, sometimes it's true, sometimes it's not the case..... You can say that about any country in the world.

Comment: @Rafee, and if ones needs to keep their sim-card working while he's abroad because he needs to have access to his chinese bank card via internet banking?

Comment: @アレックス I believe you can update new mobile number in bank. I am still using Chinese bank account overseas.

Comment: @Rafee, why update? they require a local chinese number.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done that but when I asked about that last year, they were very well willing to sell it to me in the main office of china telecom or some other company I don't remember which. I'd have to pay around $100 in rmb for it because it was a requirement - a deposit which would be topped up to my sim-card. All of $100 or nearly all, I don't remember. In other companies it's more or less the same. I decided I didn't want a sim-card for $100 even if it was a deposit and thus I didn't buy one. But I could have. It was in Guangzhou.

In Hong Kong you can officially buy a sim-card for 50HKD without your passport. Money - sim-card.

Comment: Interesting, nobody offered this option to me. Is it 100 RMB or $100 USD?

Comment: @Bai, 100 usd but in rmb

Comment: They might have tried to scam you since you are clearly a foreigner. At least in China, it is not uncommon to negotiate in many places.

Comment: @Blaszard, what scam? central office. all money would be topped up to my sim-card.

Comment: @アレックス They try to sell any products in expensive prices. Not only did I experience it in buying a SIM card but also in other products, such as a Nintendo 3DS adapter. I negotiated it so much but still purchased it in expensive price...

Comment: @Blaszard, once again: all money would be topped up to my sim-card.